# Task API for limited input devices

Tags: java

Konrad Eichstädt
07.11.2021, 11:50:00 (gestern)
an AdWords API and Google Ads API Forum
Hi There,

I'am trying to develop a smart home addon to reading google tasks. I tried this using the OAUTH2 Flow for limited devices

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/limited-input-device

I got successfull an access token but can't using them because of the following error:

"error": {

```
"code": 403,

"message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",

"errors": [

  {

    "message": "Insufficient Permission",

    "domain": "global",

    "reason": "insufficientPermissions"

  }

],

"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",

"details": [

  {

    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",

    "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",

    "domain": "googleapis.com",

    "metadata": {

      "method": "google.apps.tasks.data.v1.TaskListService.Get",

      "service": "tasks.googleapis.com"

    }

  }

]
```

}

I this correct that limited devices can't reading google tasks?

Many Thanks,

Konrad

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  As a quick first guess I would suggest that the token returned from your OAuth endpoint returned a token that is lacking a required permission.  I would suggest looking at how your token is generated and making sure it is generated with the permission required by the google endpoint.

Comment: Hi Gavin I agree with you because of this my question ist if it is  even possible using the TASK API using OAUTH2 Flow for limited devices. Because the ducomentation says this:  Zulässige Bereiche
Der OAuth 2.0-Flow für Geräte wird nur für die folgenden Bereiche unterstützt:

OpenID Connect , Google-Anmeldung
email
openid
profile
Laufwerk-API
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
YouTube API
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly